# How to getfull path from sdcard in android app?

Tags: android, sd-card

hello i used code below and i run the project in android 3.0 tablet emulator in android application  nad i get path /mnt/sdcard/ but not get fullpath.how solve it ?please help me!!And my code below

```
![package com.hope.project;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView myWebView;
    TextView mDisplay;
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;
    String name;
    String Message;
    String deviceId;
    String regId;
    IntentFilter gcmFilter;
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        final JavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(
                this);
        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface,
                "AndroidFunction");

        WebSettings settings = myWebView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                // handle stuff here
                // e.g. view.loadUrl(url);
                Log.v("log", " on ovverRide " + url);
                return true;
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // dismiss the indeterminate progress dialog
                Log.v("log", "onPageFinished: " + url);
                myWebView.setEnabled(false);

            }
        });

        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    /*  File urlName= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile();
        Log.v("log_tag", "urlNameDownload "+urlName);*/

        /* File file\[\] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles(); 
         for (File f : file)
            {
                if (f.isDirectory()) { 
                    String uri=f.getPath().substring(f.getPath().lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                    Log.v("Name", uri);
                    Log.v("Name", f.getPath()+ "");
                    Log.v("Name", f.getAbsolutePath()+ "");

                }
            }*/

        File dir = new File("mnt/sdcard/");

        File\[\] files = (new File("mnt/sdcard/")).listFiles();

        // This filter only returns directories
        FileFilter dirFilter = new FileFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir) {
                return dir.isDirectory();
            }
        };

        files = dir.listFiles(dirFilter);

        for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
            if(files\[i\].getAbsolutePath().contains("Download"))
              Log.v("log_tag","directory path : " + files\[i\].getAbsolutePath().substring(files\[i\].getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf("/") +1));
        }
    }


    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public class JavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

        JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public void DownloadUrl(String url) {
            Log.v("log", "login main url " + url);

            String file_url = url;

            new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
            /*
             * String url_new = "http://"+url; Intent i = new
             * Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); i.setData(Uri.parse(url_new));
             * startActivity(i);

*/
        }
    }

    class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Bar Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // showDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }

        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            Log.v("log", "login main url\[0\] " + f_url\[0\]);
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url\[0\]);
                name = f_url\[0\].substring(f_url\[0\].lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                // getting file length
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                        8192);

                // Output stream to write file
                // OutputStream output = new
                // FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.jpg");
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/" + name);

                // OutputStream output = new
                // FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedUrl.mp4");
                byte data\[\] = new byte\[1024\];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Updating progress bar
         * */
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            // setting progress percentage
            // pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress\[0\]));
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            // dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
            // Displaying downloaded image into image view
            // Reading image path from sdcard

            /*
             * Log.v("log","login main url\[0\] " +
             * Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()); String
             * videoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/"+name;
             * Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
             * VideoPlayActivity.class); i.putExtra("videoPath", videoPath);
             * startActivity(i);
             */

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "DownLoad Is Completed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

[image: my sdcard screen shot below:]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hardcoding `mnt/sdcard/` you should use the [Environment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) object.

Specifically:

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Will give you a file object that is automatically pointing in the proper place for the External Storage of the device that it is running on.

Also, you've posted your entire Activity. The vast majority of it is unrelated to the problem you are having. In the future it is more likely that you'll get good help on StackOverflow if you take out a smaller section of your code that specifically relates to the problem you are having. It makes it easier for people who are answering to figure out your situation.